# Minification removes semicolon from javascripts

Tags: javascript, minify

Added Later: I want to add further clarification on my concern. My concern is un-minified code without semicolon works. **But what about absence of semicolon in minified code (which is in single line)? because it indicates END of the statement.**

I have also gone through the answers of this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840845/reliable-and-convenient-javascript-minifier#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840845/reliable-and-convenient-javascript-minifier#_=_)

I have also gone through stephenwlther link.

But still my concern is not resolved. Because minifier tools removes semicolons from lot of lines.

Check this un-minified code...

```
(jQuery)(function ($) {

function statsCount(options) {
    var $this = $(this);
    options = $.extend({}, options || {}, $this.data('countToOptions') ||        {});
    $this.countTo(options);
} // NUMBERS COUNTER END

function statsAnimate() {
    // NUMBERS COUNTER START
    $('.numbers').data('countToOptions', {
        formatter: function (value, options) {
            return value.toFixed(options.decimals).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
        }
    });
    // start timer
    $('.timer').each(statsCount);
}

if (typeof (CMA) != "undefined" && CMA.elementsAnimation) {
    $('.numbers-counter').waypoint(function () {
        statsAnimate();
    },
            {offset: '70%'}
    );
} else {
    statsAnimate();
}
});
```

minifier.org giving me below code....

```
(jQuery)(function($){function statsCount(options){var $this=$(this);options=$.extend({},options||{},$this.data('countToOptions')||});$this.countTo(options)}function statsAnimate()$('.numbers').data('countToOptions',formatter:function(value,options){return value.toFixed(options.decimals).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,',')}});$('.timer').each(statsCount)}if(typeof(CMA)!="undefined"&&CMA.elementsAnimation){$('.numbers-counter').waypoint(function()statsAnimate()},offset:'70%'})}else{statsAnimate()}})
```

Note the absence of semicolon at the end and from lot of places.

If this correct??

Comment: Is the minified code not working? Semicolons are optional in javascript. Minifiers try to decrease as many bytes as they can without breaking your code

Comment: Semicolons are **not** optional in JavaScript: the way you put it, it seems that one can remove all semicolons. The thing is that *some* semicolons are optional, some are unnecessary and some are even wrong.

Comment: @MukeshSoni i am worried to test whether minified code is working or not as i am working on live and high-traffic news portal site. That is why i decided to confirm.

Comment: I hope you have a test environment to test your code before it goes to production. 

@gerardo - javascript engine does automatic semicolon insertion for you. But minifiers remove semicolon in a way that it will not result in wrong interpretation as opposed to code with semicolon

Comment: @MukeshSoni try a for loop without semicolons separating the expressions.., what I'm saying is that, for someone that doesn't know JS that much (which may be OP's case), your statement might make him/her think that *all* semicolons are optional. You could say: *"semicolons as **statement terminators** are optional"*.

Comment: Can you give a jsfiddle or jsbin link for the for loop example?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado i believe i did not precisely express my concern. So added few more lines in question.

Comment: You can still try your code locally without going to the production server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do I add semi-colons in JS to prevent minification errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812066/where-do-i-add-semi-colons-in-js-to-prevent-minification-errors)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion) works even without newlines for most constructs, therefore it is often possible to remove semicolons *and* newlines. I don't know what minifier you are using, but all commonly-used ones today are precise enough to insert semicolons just where necessary to preserve the original parse, removing unneeded ones. See also https://github.com/standard/standard/blob/caa357395b48bc5e1cced3c85a5eb47bbf4aeac8/RULES.md#helpful-reading.